# How do I ssh into my linux machine at home?

Tags: linux, unix, ssh

It's a dell ubuntu.
But I don't know why I can't do:

myuser@192.168.0.103

which is my local-ip.

Comment: Are you trying to connect from another linux box on the same LAN?

Comment: I'm on a windows machine, on the same lAN.

Answer (score 4):

You should start with some basics.

1. If `192.168` is your local LAN and you have a Ubuntu and another Windows machine wired to it, you first need to confirm if you can `ping` from one to the other
2. Once you know the two machines can 'see' each other over the LAN,
   you can check if SSHd is active on the Ubuntu machine.

   - you can do a '[`netstat -l`](http://www.basicconfig.com/linuxnetwork/netstat)' on the Ubuntu to look for `22/tcp` being LISTEN'ed on
   - you can then do a '`telnet ubuntu_ip 22`' from the Windows machine to check nothing is blocking that connectivity

     - if you get a 'connection refused' someone is blocking SSH
       (or, there is no SSHd listening in the first place)
3. Also, while you try things, look at [Ubuntu log files](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-gnome-system-log-viewer/) to check for related [log lines](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LinuxLogFiles)

   - `/var/log/messages`
   - `/var/log/auth.log`
   - `/var/log/secure`

Answer (score 2):

Ok, need some more info from you first:

Can you ssh in from any other pc?

What software are you using on the win client? Putty?

Are you getting a connection refused or a time out error?

Openssh-server is not installed on most distros automaticly, did you install it on your "dell Ubuntu" box? Without it you can't get remote access. 'Sudo apt-get install ssh' should do the trick.

Can you ping the ip?

Comment: Also the ssh service must be started. I think installing ssh trough apt-get also starts it but I'm not sure.